# Xamarin Forms - Tabbed View?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I need to create a popup, in which there will be some tabs, each of them containing a listview. I know that there is a TabbedPage, but I need a "TabbedView" so I can build my popup using the Xlabs PopupLayout. How do I do this in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: We also need a TabbedView. TabbedPage is rubbish because it doesn't allow for a header/footer (i.e. it has to take up the whole screen), and CarouselView doesn't have the same functionality as a TabbedPage on each of the platforms. What's needed is to actually smash these two controls together to create a TabbedView as you have said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom control yourself.

(imagine you want  to create 3 tabs)

For example you can have a view that it's a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns.

1st row you set the buttons set the RowHeight to auto or a size you want, and add each button to each column.

On row 2 you can have a ContentView with RowHeight of * (to fill the rest of the space) , you should also set GridSpan to 3 columns so it will fill all width available on the grid.

Then when you click a button you just have to set the ContentView view to what you want for that particular tab., you can also have animations before changing the content.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I already did that, but I wanted to see if there is another option. Anyway, thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @Ilia Stoilov Have u found any better solution for the same?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 5):

Please have a look at [TabView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.TabView) plugin.

I was facing a similar problem in my past project and decided to create a plugin from my implementation.

I've also included a sample project for using TabView [here](https://github.com/chaosifier/TabView), please have a look.

The plugin is also available in NuGet. Enter the following command in package management console to install the latest version of the plugin in your project:

```
PM> Install-Package Xam.Plugin.TabView
```

Since TabView inherits from ContentView, you can use it like any other Views in Xamarin.
Here's an example:

```
var tabView = new TabViewControl(new List<TabItem>()
{
    new TabItem(
        "Tab 1",
        new Image{
            Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png")),
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
            BackgroundColor = Color.LightBlue
        }),
    new TabItem(
        "Tab 2",
        new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                new Label(){
                    FontSize = 18,
                    Text = "This is a label control.",
                    TextColor = Color.Green,
                }
            },
            BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
            Padding = 10
        }),
    new TabItem(
        "Tab 3",
        new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                new ListView(){
                    ItemsSource = new string[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6" }
                }
            },
            BackgroundColor = Color.LightSalmon,
            Padding = 10
        })
});
tabView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
this.Content = tabView;
```

Comment: Are these Tabs swipable like Tabbed page?

Comment: What if I have more tabs, like 7? Does your plugin contain something like horizonal scroll?