# How to add Navigation buttons to the header onMaster Detail Page with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am trying to create a similar header as in the Google Plus app (iOS) using Xamarin Forms.
I already have the left menu (drawer) working as expected, but I am not able to find a way to add more buttons (like the search loop icon) and the tabbed / slide pages right underneath.

I am not interested in the tabbed menu at the bottom, just need the loop icon on the right hand side and the 3 tabbed menus (Recommended, member and yours).

Should I add this to each page that is child of the master detail page or this somehow goes to the Master Detail Page. I cannot figure out how.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your search-option in the top, you can just add a `ToolbarItem` to your page:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Search" Icon="MySearchIcon.png" Order="Primary" 
                Command="{Binding SearchCommandBinding}" />
        ...
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <!-- Here are your UI Elements -->
</ContentPage>
```

And for your TabbedPage... yeah, that's also your answer. You can use a [TabbedPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/) from Xamarin (instead of a ContentPage, or whatever you use).

Just set the `Detail` from your `MasterDetailPage` to a TabbedPage and that's it.

Alternatively, you can just add a [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/) and design it like a Tabs. With this, you have the same UI over all platforms (more infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947255/2653134)).

Comment: Hi mate, yes I just found out about the ToolbarItems which gave me a solution for the button on the top right.

Comment: But for tue tabbed page... What I have is a listview inside a content page, so i should just add tabbed view before tue listview? Will that look like as it is part of the header? I will have to test it

Comment: You can make it look like it is a part of the top bar. Alternatively: You always have the option to create your top bar by yourself, and not use the default one (it takes more time and more design specific things, but this is also a way you can go)

Comment: Joehl how can i make it look as it is part of the top bar? Like where would i set the background colour? Should this be a property of each menuitem?

Comment: You can find further informations here -> https://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2014/12/19/creating-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-10-designing-and-developing-the-user-interface/

It's a long post, but you should find your answer there. Oterwise: Just ask another specific question here on SO.