# How to show an Image on top of a tabbed view in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am using `Xamarin.Forms` and trying to achieve the next layout:
[image: Layout Image]
I want to keep the native look and feel for each platform (i.e: `iOS` tabs will be shown in bottom.), I just want to add an extra image on top of the tabbed view. I have been looking around and can't find any one providing a way for this to work. I just want to make sure and ask if this is actually doable in `Xamarin.Forms` while maintaining native look and feel for all platforms?

Comment: see the alternative answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936157/xamarin-forms-tabbed-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible (using Xamarin Forms) to do this. TabbedPage is a Control that fills the entire display.

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84597/tabbedview) there is a interesting discussion about "TabView".

I think you can use some other controls to try to do the same thing. For example, buttons + CarouselView.

Otherwise on GitHub there are some guys that have tried to implement what you need.. [TabView](https://github.com/gruan01/XFControls/blob/master/XFControls/Documents/TabView.md)